# map function similar to python in swift

Tags: python, ios, swift, dictionary

I was trying to convert the below **python** code to **swift**

**Python code**

```
a0,a1,a2= map(int, [1,2,3])
print(a0,a1,a2)
```

> **Output:** 1 2 3

**Swift code**

```
var a0,a1,a2:Int = [1,2,3]."What should be code here?"
```

Is there any one line solution for mapping object in **swift** like **python** ?

> **Note** I already know that i can get the value with index, but i need a solution like **python**

Comment: Why do you need this, what exactly are you trying to do? Where does the array come from and why do you know it's going to contain 3 elements?

Comment: You don't have to use `map()` for that, `a0,a1,a2=[1,2,3]` is just fine. In Swift, you can't use arrays for that but tuples: `let (a1, a2, a3) = (1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: @Squall that's really helpful. I am trying to implement with tuple. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a destructuring assignment in Python there, but Swift **doesn't support it** for arrays. You can only do that with tuples, like Squall pointed out in a comment.

Swift has a map function though, which you can use like so:

```
let result = [1, 2, 3].map { n in
    // `myFunction` could be any function or initializer you want
    return myFunction(n)
}
```

And a shorter equivalent is:

```
let result = [1, 2, 3].map(myFunction)
```

A translation of your code would be:

```
let result = [1, 2, 3].map { n in
    return Int(n)
}
```

This code **does nothing though**, because the array is already an array of int's.

Comment: Can you give me  a complete implementation for the fn initializer or function ?